# PHP Dropdown menu

Tags: php, web

```
<br><h2>Select a Tag</h2></br>

<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("portal", $con);

$query = "SELECT tag_name FROM tags";
$result = mysql_query($query);

?>
<select name="tag_name" id="abc">
<option size=30 selected>Select</option>
<?php
while($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>
<option value ="<?php echo $array['tag_name'];?>"><?php echo $array['tag_name'];?>      
</option>
 <?php

}
?>
</select>     <br><br>
```

This is a snippet of code for getting the dropdown menu in the page.
I have a database named portal and table named tags with tag_name as the attribute.
Do help me to find the error in the program.
I am not getting the tag_names in the dropdown menu

Comment: If nothing else, you've got two `<?php` back-to-back, which is a syntax-error.

Comment: Are you sure that your query is OK and you have any result?

Comment: Dusan : How to check for that ?

Comment: Try to execute this query in some MySQL client (like phpMyAdmin) add see if there is any results.

Answer (score 2):

```
</option>
 <?php
 <?php
}
```

Above is an error in your code.

You repeated `<?php`

Comment: Still having problems even after removing it,the same problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

First things first:
Could you tell me if the count of  is greater then zero?
Try "SELECT `tag_name` FROM tags" (with the weird quotes) instead of "SELECT tag_name FROM tags" to make the select statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
<br><h2>Select a Tag</h2></br>

<?php

  // Connect to database
  // NEVER use the root user in a production environment!
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con) {
    // NEVER show the result of mysql_error() in a production environment!
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("portal", $con);

  // Run the query (and check the result)
  $query = "SELECT tag_name FROM tags";
  if (!$result = mysql_query($query)) {
    die("MySQL error at query: ".mysql_error());
  }

  if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {

    // Draw the select if the query returned more than 0 rows, or display an error

?>

<select name="tag_name" id="abc">
  <option size=30 selected>Select</option>

  <?php while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $array['tag_name'];?>"><?php echo $array['tag_name'];?></option>
  <?php } ?>

</select><br><br>

<?php } else { ?>

Query returned 0 results!

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Query is returning 0 results,any reasons for this.

Comment: Because your table `tags` in the database `portal` on the server `localhost` has no records in it.